# Azure + Nodejs 400 Bad Request when contentType="application/json"

Tags: node.js, jquery, azure, express, ember-data

I have an Node.js, Express app that serves as an REST api for Emberjs RESTAdapter. I trying to get this working on Windows Azure. When Ember makes the HTTP request on "/examples/1" as below gives me a 400, Bad Request.

After troubleshooting it seems like the error depends on the request header content type.

- Visiting the "(domain)/users/1" in a web-browser prints out the correct json in the browser window.
- Running Jquery ajax calls gives me the following results:

  This does not work:

  ```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/users/1",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  ```

  But, when switching to this, it works.

  ```
  $.ajax({
     url: "/users/1",
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
  }).done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
  ```

Now, how do I set up my nodejs/azure solution to allow http requests with content type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"?

**Update**

After comments, this is the server side code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){

   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/WebContent'));
   app.use(express.cookieParser());

});

app.get('/:param/:id', function(req, res) {
   res.json(200, {user: {id:1, name: 'tester'}} )
});

app.get('/:param', function(req, res) {
   res.json(200, {users: [{id:1, name: 'tester'}]})
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: You should also post the corresponding code on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I think I may have also run across this and found a solution.  For me, the problem is the way [express treats the empty body as invalid JSON](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1316) when you set the `ContentType: application/json` header on a `GET` request.

The suggested work around is to set the contentType to `text/plain` if you are not sending data.